# Where to view completed tasks in Google Task Queue?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

My Cloud Task Queue dashboard for a particular task looks like this:

[image: Cloud Task Queue dashboard]

It seems to only show pending tasks and tasks that errored out and need to be retried. How can I view completed tasks as well? 
My reason for wanting completed tasks on this page is so I can click on their logs.